# Where is the save file for Rogue Legacy located?

Tags: rogue-legacy

I would like to junction the save location on my computer to where I want it on my flash drive, so I can take it with me, but I'm not quite sure where the files are located.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ah, here they are. The save files are located in

```
C:/Users/<your user>/My Documents/SavedGames/RogueLegacy
```

Comment: Or on OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/RogueLegacyStorageContainer/`

Answer (score 13):

Or for Linux:

```
~/.local/share/RogueLegacyStorageContainer/
```

You can copy the entire folder or an individual profile.

Comment: Mine was in `~/.local/share/RogueLegacy/RogueLegacyStorageContainer/AllPlayers`, but wouldn't know without this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, they may have moved it in newer versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the locations of the save games on Mac, PC and Linux, as well as what each file means within the save game:

- Windows/PC: `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SavedGames\RogueLegacy\`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/RogueLegacy/`
- Linux: `$XDG_DATA_HOME/RogueLegacy/`

Steps to find the path:

- Open the File Explore
- Paste `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\SavedGames\RogueLegacy\`
- Press Enter

Each save game has x5 files, and this is what each one contains:

- RogueLegacyBP.rcdat – Upgrade Data
- RogueLegacyLineage.rcdat – Lineage Data
- RogueLegacyMap.rcdat – Minimap Data
- RogueLegacyMapData.rcdat – Rooms, Object, Enemies, etc. Data
- RogueLegacyPlayer.rcdat – Player Configuration Data (runes, equipment, etc.)

If you need the Configuration Files:

- Windows/PC: `%APPDATA%\Rogue Legacy\`
- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/RogueLegacy/`
- Linux: `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/RogueLegacy/`

Source: [FileLocations](https://www.filelocations.com/rogue-legacy-save-file-location/)